# In analysis of PSRS Why O(p^2 log p^2) = O(p^2 log p)?

Tags: big-o, parallel-processing

Analysis of PSRS (Parallel sorting by regular sampling)
In Computation part.
Why Big-o of Sorting regular samples : 
O(p^2 log p^2) = O(p^2 log p) ?
Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because log p² = 2 log p (that's a property of logarithms) and using Big-O notation lets you ignore the multiplicative constant.

Answer (score 1):

O(p^2 log p^2) = O(2p^2 log p), by properties of logarithms. And O(kg) = O(g) where k is a constant. Therefore you can remove the 2 to arrive at O(p^2 log p).